# barplot data does not correspond to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code producing a stacked barplot in ggplot

```
data_age <- data.frame(age = as.factor(c("16 to 20", "21 to 24", "25 to 30", "31 to 40", "40+")),
                   total = c(740, 1092, 855, 525, 182),
                   perc_total = c(22, 32, 25, 15, 5))

g_age <- ggplot(data_age , aes(1, perc_total, fill = age, label = perc_total)) +
 geom_bar(stat ="identity") +
 geom_text(size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), colour = "black") + 
 coord_flip() +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
 scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2), breaks = 1) +
 scale_fill_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = NULL, keyheight = 0.5, keywidth = 0.5, direction = "horizontal"), values = c("#FFFFB2", "#FECC5C", "#FD8D3C", "#F03B20", "#BD0026")) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    legend.position="bottom")
```

[Which results in this barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUlH8.jpg)

However I need the order of the data to be reversed. I can achieve that by doing the following

```
g_age_2 <- ggplot(data_age , aes(1, perc_total, fill = levels(age)[5:1], label = perc_total)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity") +
  geom_text(size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), colour = "black") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2), breaks = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = NULL, keyheight = 0.5, keywidth = 0.5, direction = "horizontal"), values = c("#BD0026", "#F03B20", "#FD8D3C", "#FECC5C", "#FFFFB2")) + ## Inverted the colors too
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    legend.position="bottom")
```

[And this plot follows the order and the colors that I want, but the legend does not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrVJ8.jpg)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
g_age <- ggplot(data_age , aes(1, perc_total, fill = age, label = perc_total)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5,reverse = TRUE), colour = "black") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2), breaks = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = NULL, keyheight = 0.5, keywidth = 0.5, direction = "horizontal"),
                    values = c("#FFFFB2", "#FECC5C", "#FD8D3C", "#F03B20", "#BD0026")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Note the addition of `position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` to `geom_bar()` and to `geom_text()` as well.
I also replaced the `theme` with `theme_void()` to remove everything and just have `theme()` for setting the position of the legend.

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! I adapted to my original code and it worked the way I intended